# How to set constraints in WinForm?

Tags: winforms

I created `UserControl` and put there a two `GroupBox` one at the top and one at the bottom... there is a screenshot

[image]

And then when I put this `UserControl` with my a views within to `TabController` I got such a result

[image]

So, as you see in the main form it looks like it is not enough space for all views within `UserControl`

Question is - is there a way to set that `GroupBox` at the top will take 50% of the height and `GroupBox` at the bottom will take also 50% of the height, such way this two `GroupBox` view will take 100% of the height each for 50%...

Comment: use `SplitContainer`?

Comment: @ASh but `SplitContainer` take an option to user to move it... I don't want that user can move my views...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alternatively use `TableLayoutPanel` with two rows (each row gets 50% height)

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
    this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
    this.groupBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // tableLayoutPanel1
    // 
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1, 0, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2, 0, 2);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 4F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(507, 408);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // groupBox1
    // 
    this.groupBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
    this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
    this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(501, 196);
    this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
    this.groupBox1.Text = "groupBox1";
    // 
    // groupBox2
    // 
    this.groupBox2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.groupBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 209);
    this.groupBox2.Name = "groupBox2";
    this.groupBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(501, 196);
    this.groupBox2.TabIndex = 1;
    this.groupBox2.TabStop = false;
    this.groupBox2.Text = "groupBox2";
    // 
    // Form3
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(513, 414);
    this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
    this.Name = "Form3";
    this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
    this.Text = "Form3";
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

#endregion

private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox2;
```

[image: TableLayoutPanel]

Comment: But as far as I see there is no way to set (for example) 80 / 20, this option just in `SplitContainer`, right?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, TableLayoutPanel can have multiple Rows and Columns with different proportions. It can be done via Designer: see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWkZI.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SplitContainer` (`IsSplitterFixed = true;` will not allow to change proportions)

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
    this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
    this.groupBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
    this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
    this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
    this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // splitContainer1
    // 
    this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
    this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
    this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
    this.splitContainer1.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal;
    // 
    // splitContainer1.Panel1
    // 
    this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
    // 
    // splitContainer1.Panel2
    // 
    this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
    this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(459, 395);
    this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 197;
    this.splitContainer1.SplitterWidth = 1;
    this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // groupBox1
    // 
    this.groupBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
    this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(459, 197);
    this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
    this.groupBox1.Text = "groupBox1";
    // 
    // groupBox2
    // 
    this.groupBox2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.groupBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.groupBox2.Name = "groupBox2";
    this.groupBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(459, 197);
    this.groupBox2.TabIndex = 0;
    this.groupBox2.TabStop = false;
    this.groupBox2.Text = "groupBox2";
    // 
    // Form2
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(465, 401);
    this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
    this.Name = "Form2";
    this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
    this.Text = "Form2";
    this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
    this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

#endregion

private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer1;
private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox2;
```

[image: SplitContainer]

Comment: And one more question, why do you use dynamic view creation instead of design? I mean UI approach

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, I made this form entirely in WinForms designer and then copied InitializeComponent() from Form3.Designer.cs file for you to easily reproduce the same Form. Dynamic view creation can be necessary in cases when there are many repeating elements (and even then I can get away with one heavily-customized DataGridView).